# How can I animate an image with CSS3/webkit animation to slide in from the left side of the screen, wait a few seconds, then slide back off screen?

Tags: html, css

I'm completely new to the world of animation and coding in general, scouring the internet I was able to find something close to what I want but right now the code only animates the image to slide in from the left but not slide back off screen after waiting for 10 seconds.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .wrapper {
                position: relative;
                overflow: hidden;
                width: 500px;
                height: 500px;
            }

            #slide {
                position: absolute;
                left: -130px;
                width: 130px;
                height: 330px;
                -webkit-animation: slide 10s 0s 1;
                -webkit-animation: slide 0.5s forwards;
                -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
                animation: slide 2s forwards;
                transition: 4s;
            }

            @-webkit-keyframes slide {
                100% { left: 0; }
            }

            @keyframes slide {
                100% { left: 0; }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <img id="slide" src="http://i.imgur.com/uqMkMLV.png" />
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

How can I fix this to make the image slide back off screen after it's been on screen for 10 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

```
@keyframes slide {
    from {
        // declare animation
    }

    to {
        // declare animation
    }
}
```

This code can achieve what you want.

```
@keyframes slide {
    0% {
        left: -330px
    }

    10% {
        left: 0px
    }

    90% {
        left: 0px
    }

    100% {
        left: -330px
    }
}
```

Just try to adjust the animation-duration. Cheers!

Comment: This is starting to make a lot more sense so far, thanks!  My only hangup now is editing durations, when the image is fully on screen (at the 50% bracket in @keyframes) I want it to sit there for 10 seconds, how can I achieve that?